# ExoPlayer Notifications appear onTop of notification bar in Android 12

Tags: exoplayer, android-music-player, android-12, background-music

[image]

The Noticiation laods fine but its located ontop of my notification bar.

I'am using Android 12 on a Noxia X10

Please Help me out

Code:

```kotlin
        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                UPDATE_ALERT_ID,
                UPDATE_ALERT,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
            )
            serviceChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            serviceChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            service.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
```

This is how I Build the notifications

I have tried changing the Importance of the notification but it its not where the issue is from.

Code:

```kotlin
      val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        createChannel(notificationManager)
        playerNotificationBuild = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, CHANNEL_ID,
            object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
                override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
                    return activeAudio?.song_name.toString()
                }

                override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java);
                    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        applicationContext, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    )
                }

                override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence? {
                    return activeAudio?.song_artist
                }

                override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
                    player: Player,
                    callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
                ): Bitmap? {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                }

            }).setNotificationListener(object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {

            override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
                super.onNotificationCancelled(notificationId, dismissedByUser)
                removeNotification()
                stopSelf()
                stopForeground(true)
            }

            override fun onNotificationPosted(notificationId: Int, notification: Notification, ongoing: Boolean) {
                super.onNotificationPosted(notificationId, notification, ongoing)
                if (ongoing) startForeground(notificationId, notification) else stopForeground(false)
            }
        })
        playerNotificationManager = playerNotificationBuild!!.build()
        playerNotificationManager!!.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession!!.sessionToken)
        playerNotificationManager!!.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
      //  playerNotificationManager!!.setControlDispatcher(DefaultControlDispatcher(0, 0))
        playerNotificationManager!!.setPriority(PRIORITY_LOW)
        playerNotificationManager!!.setPlayer(mSimpleExoPlayer)
```

Comment: any solution to this found ?